# ByteBuffer byte padding in Java

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm working on a Java program in which I need to convert a `short` into two bytes (which will then be packed into a data packet).  I'm using a `ByteBuffer` to perform the conversion, and it seems to work, but I'm seeing some apparent byte padding which I don't quite understand.

Here's a simple example I wrote:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        short i = 27015;
        String s = Integer.toHexString(i);

        System.out.println( "i = " + i );
        System.out.println( "s = " + s );
        System.out.println( "---" );

        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        b.putShort(i);

        System.out.printf("0x%H\n", b.getShort(0));
        System.out.println( "---" );

        byte[] a = b.array();

        for( int j = 0; j < a.length; j++ )
            System.out.printf("a[" + j + "] = 0x%H\n", a[j]);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This program produces the following output:

```
i = 27015
s = 6987
---
0x6987
---
a[0] = 0x69
a[1] = 0xFFFFFF87
```

When the `ByteBuffer` is converted to a `byte` array, why is the second byte padded with 0xFF?  It seems like the second element of the array should be `0x87` instead of `0xFFFFFF87`.  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: The byte `0x87` is negative, has its high bit set. Converted to an int other one get 0xFFFFFF87, a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the ByteBuffer is converted to a byte array, why is the second byte padded with 0xFF?

When you print with `%H` it casts the byte into an int.  It id not the byte in the ByteBuffer which has has this many bit, but the way it is being printed.  I suggest using `Byte.toHexString(a[j])` instead.

Comment: Thanks for condensing my confusion down to a much more concise question, and thanks for your answer.  That makes complete sense.  It never occurred to me that the issue was in the `printf()` conversion.

Comment: When I have a test fail, at least 50% of the time it's due to something wrong with the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
   System.out.printf("a[" + j + "] = 0x%H\n", ((int) a[j]) & 0xFF);
```

The `& 0xFF` operation will cut the highest three bytes, that are created after the conversion to an int.

FYI: `((int) a[j]) & 0xFF` can be written as `a[j] & 0xFF` and will compile exactly the same. But I wrote it initially like that to clarify what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it and that does indeed make the output more clear.